# Does it make sense to type cast literals?

Tags: c++, c, embedded

So I am working on memory constrained embedded system and want to save as much bytes as possible. If, in my code if I have statements like:

```
b = a << 1;
```

or

```
b += 1;
```

where `a` and `b` are `uint8_t`. Is it beneficial to type cast the literal to same type or is it done by compiler:

```
b = a << (uint8_t) 1;

b += (uint8_t) 1;
```

Comment: It's not going to make any difference to the size  of the actual named variables `a` and `b`.

Comment: I have seen compilers complain about constants in particular when you do a ones complement (~1234).  Otherwise if the compiler complains then you clearly need to do it, otherwise compiler specific.

Comment: In the specific case of `b += 1;` the best way to write it is `++b;`. But that doesn't address the more general form of this question, such as `b += 2;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it beneficial to tye cast the literal to same type or is it done by compiler:

You are at the mercy of the compiler with respect to how it stores the values of constants in binaries it creates.  There is no special reason to think that casts such as you propose will change the representation used, as they nominally express *runtime* conversions (from `int`, in this case).  Moreover, and without going into details, C specifies that the operands of arithmetic operations will be promoted to a type at least as wide as `int` for the purpose of computing the results of arithmetic operations.  A compiler might plausibly pre-compute such a conversion, effectively nullifying your casts altogether.

Your casts might actually be worse, however, if they happen to prevent the compiler from recognizing opportunities to avoid storing constant values at all.  For example, speculatively, if your target CPU has a specific instruction to increment the value of a register by exactly 1, then it might use that to implement

```
b += 1;
```

... but fail to recognize that it can do the same thing with

```
b += (uint8_t) 1;
```

... on account of `(uint8_t) 1` being a non-primary expression.

Use casts sparingly, and only as necessary to describe the *semantics* of your program.  Rely on your compiler to do a good job, and if it doesn't then look for a better one.  Compilers for embedded environments can usually be relied upon to understand the importance of minimizing code size, and even compilers for general-purpose platforms often have options to request optimization for minimum code size.

Comment: There are places where it does matter though, such as  `uint64_t = (uint64_t)1 << 56`;  Otherwise the operation is evaluated using int, which is an issue in the common case where `int` is less that 64 bits.

Comment: Certainly, @nos, but that's beyond the scope of the question.  The OP was asking about the effect of casts on *the size of the compiled binary*, and my comments are focused there.  Neverthless, I did say one should use casts *as necessary to describe the semantics of your program*, which is what you're talking about.

Answer (score 3):

In this case it doesn't matter because any integer value whose type has a lower rank than `int` is automatically promoted to `int` when used in an expression.

Comment: [One reference on this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion)

Answer (score 3):

In the provided examples the benefit is to maintain *sign-agreement* rather then *type-agreement*.  Type agreement in this case is defeated in any case by type promotion rules;  the literal operand, after being cast to `uint8_t` will be promoted to `unsigned int`.  Without the cast it would be promoted to `int` and in some expressions could potentially produce unintended or undefined results (though not in these examples - right-shift for example is ambiguous for a negative signed value).

An arguably better way of maintaining *sign-agreement* is to use the unsigned literal suffix `u`:

```
b = a << 1u ;
b += 1u ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Literals like in your examples won't likely be stored as separate numeric constants, but will be integrated in the machine code instructions. In your case, the result will be some instruction like "logical left shift register x, 1". The number will then be as large as required for the particular instruction, no matter what the higher level C language says.

These are the kind of optimizations you should leave to the compiler. That goes for integer constants ("literals"), `#define` ones and usually also for enums.

However, if you have constants used as `const` variables, you could manually pick the smallest needed type in order to save flash. If you declare something like for example `static const int x = 123;` then you risk blocking the compiler from using any smaller type than whatever `int` happens to be.

The types `uint_leastn_t` from stdint.h were intended to use for memory optimizations. If you write `static const uint_least8_t = 123;` then the compiler will pick the smallest type available, of at least 8 bytes. (Which most likely will yield the very same result as `uint8_t` on most systems.)

Answer (score 0):

I did some experimentation on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/).

```
#include <cstdint>

uint64_t A()
{
    return uint64_t{1} << 4;
}

uint64_t B()
{
    return static_cast<uint64_t>(1) << 4;
}

uint64_t C()
{
    return uint64_t(1) << 4;
}

// uint64_t D()
// {
//     return uint8_t{256}; <--- Compile time error
// }

uint64_t E()
{
    return static_cast<uint8_t>(256);
}

uint64_t F()
{
    return uint8_t(256);
}
```

Clang 11.0.1 with `-std=c++20 -O1` generated the following assembler:

```
A():                                  # @A()
        mov     eax, 16
        ret
B():                                  # @B()
        mov     eax, 16
        ret
C():                                  # @C()
        mov     eax, 16
        ret
E():                                  # @E()
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
F():                                  # @F()
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

and the following error for `D()`

```
<source>:20:20: error: constant expression evaluates to 256 which cannot be narrowed to type 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wc++11-narrowing]
    return uint8_t{256};
                   ^~~
<source>:20:20: note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue
    return uint8_t{256};
                   ^~~
                   static_cast<uint8_t>( )
<source>:20:20: warning: implicit conversion from 'int' to 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') changes value from 256 to 0 [-Wconstant-conversion]
    return uint8_t{256};
                  ~^~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

GCC 10.2 with `-std=c++20 -O1` generated the following assembler:

```
A():
        mov     eax, 16
        ret
B():
        mov     eax, 16
        ret
C():
        mov     eax, 16
        ret
E():
        mov     eax, 0
        ret
F():
        mov     eax, 0
        ret
```

and the following error for `D()`

```
<source>: In function 'uint64_t D()':
<source>:20:23: error: narrowing conversion of '256' from 'int' to 'uint8_t' {aka 'unsigned char'} [-Wnarrowing]
   20 |     return uint8_t{256};
      |                       ^
Compiler returned: 1
```

Conclusions

- Worrying about a compiler not recognising a primary expression BEFORE testing is premature optimisation
- Using `{}` is superior to `()` or `static_cast` because it ensures our number literals are safely within range of our target type.
- If we WANT to do something that `{}` doesn't allow, we will be forced to state our intentions to the compiler AND therefore other developers (see clangs compile error `note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue`)